Composer using content-hash as an autoloader-suffix causes PHP class conflicts
I have a custom GitHub action which runs composer install -o --no-dev on release to install the dependencies, ZIPs the repo and attaches it to the release. Recently this action started generating the same class names even for different repositories, for some reason the hash used in class names is not random anymore.
This causes an error when multiple repos are then used in the code, since the Composer autoloader classes are the same, for example:
Fatal error: Cannot declare class ComposerAutoloaderInit439eaff7cf205a5b40a2e3bddaab853c, because the name is already in use
What may be the reason? Thanks
I tried adding --no-cache to the composer install assuming that composer started caching class maps in recent versions, but the issue persists.
UPDATE: I realized this occurs because different repos have the same dependencies, and Composer now uses content-hash (which is the same since dependencies are the same) as an autoloader suffix, is there a way to force Composer to use a random string even if content-hash is present in composer.lock?
